# What's the pattern to intercept constructor execution in TypeScript using aspect.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, aop

What's the pattern to intercept constructor execution in TypeScript using aspect.js?

It's not documented AFAICT, and my workaround for now is to add a static factory method called `new` to each class, then statically intercept that using `beforeStaticMethod` advice:

```
import { Wove as Advised } from 'aspect.js'
import './aspects/Aspect'
import './aspects/Aspect2'

@Advised()
export default class Thing {
  static new (s: string = '', t: number = 0) {
    return new Thing(...arguments)
  }
  // ...
}
```

then, in an aspect:

```
import {
  Metadata,
  beforeStaticMethod,
  beforeMethod,
  afterStaticMethod,
  afterMethod,
  beforeGetter,
  beforeSetter,
  afterGetter,
  afterSetter
} from 'aspect.js'

export default class Aspect {
  @beforeStaticMethod({ classNamePattern: /.*/, methodNamePattern: /^new$/ })
  beforeNew (meta: Metadata) {
    console.log('Aspect beforeNew')
  }
  // ...
}
```

This works, but it's unnatural for TypeScript/JavaScript developers to use the `new` method rather than the conventional `new Thing()` syntax.